# PHP OOP programming question

Tags: php, oop, class, new-operator, fatal-error

Hi
I was given a link to php classes. I am trying to make a domain availability checker. I managed to get a domain whois class from there but having a problem running it. I have included the class in my page, instatiated it and tried to run the example code. When i load it, it is displaying the class on my site and then below saying: Fatal error: Class 'domain' not found in C:\wamp\www\tes.php on line 8. I don't get it my path is obviously right if it can display the class on screen.

Heres my code. Please bear in mind this is the example code that was supplied with the class.

```
<?php
require_once('classes/domain.class.php');

$choice = 'amazing.co.uk';


// Initializing class
$domain=new domain($choice);

// Printing out whois data
echo $domain->info()."<br>";

// Printing out whois data in HTML format
echo $domain->html_info()."<br><br>";

// Checking if domain is available
if($domain->is_available()){
    echo "Domain is available<br>";
}else{
    echo "Domain is not Available<br>";
}

// Printing out whois host of domain
echo "Whois Server: ".$domain->get_whois_server()."<br>";

// Printing out name of domain without tld
echo "Domain: ".$domain->get_domain()."<br>";

// Printing out tld name of domain
echo "Tld: ".$domain->get_tld()."<br>";

// Checking if domain name is valid
if($domain->is_valid()){
    echo "Domain name is valid!<br>";
}else{
    echo "Domain name isn't valid!<br>";
}

// Getting all suppoerted TLD's
$tlds=$domain->get_tlds();
for($i=0;$i<count($tlds);$i++){
    echo $tlds[$i]."<br>";
}


?>
```

Thanks in advance and all help appreciated.

Regards 
Joe

Comment: bah, just parse the whois output yourself. It is trivial.

Comment: Please post the content of 'classes/domain.class.php' (at least the first few lines and the end). With the content of that file, it's hard to find a bug.

Comment: Instead you might try using http://pear.php.net/net_whois - gives you a very easy way to do this.

Comment: Within `domain.class.php` what does the line say `class _____{`

Comment: "displayed the class on my site" ... like it output the code into the page? That sounds like the included file doesn't have the <?php tag in it (or it's corrupted somehow)

Comment: class was defined correct but the class id downloaded was using short tags and WAMP didnt like that so failed lol But now its saying functions are depricated "Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in " does that mean that the class ive downloaded is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok steps to resolving this.

- Open up the class file:
- Check the line that defines the class, it should look something like:

  `class domain
  {
     /*...*/
  }`

Make sure that the class name is the same.

Note: Remember for a php file to be avalaible at runtime it must have a starting `<?php` at the first line of your class file.

Answer (score 1):

The class domain is probably not defined in: classes/domain.class.php

Comment: class was defined correct but the class id downloaded was using short tags and WAMP didnt like that so failed lol But now its saying functions are depricated "Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in " does that mean that the class ive downloaded is pretty much useless.